# Fetching data & hide/show feature display of result only works AFTER 1st time of click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

With my very limited knowledge of javascript, AJAX, have managed to combine two functions by using two separate scripts.
By click of a button it fetches data from a server and performs a show/hide feature of the result.
However, here is one problem. At the 1st click, and only the 1st click, nothing happens at all, which I am guessing the data is only fetched from server. After that the data hides and reveals at subsequent clicks of button as it should do.

How can I change the script so that at the 1st click, data is fetched AND displayed, since data is supposed to be displayed on request, as there will be many lines of data.

```
function sendIt() {

x =  (document.getElementById('part_number_id').value);


var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();



$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'serv_reply20.php',
data: {name: x},
success: function(data){
    $('#result').html(data);

}
});


}


</script>
<style>
p {
background: #dad;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

</head>

The other part of the HTML is :
 <button onclick="sendIt()">Expand</button>
 <script>
 $( "button" ).click(function() {
 $( "p" ).toggle( "slow" );
 });
 </script>

<form name="expand_discount_form" >
<input type="hidden" id="part_number_id" name="part_number" value="<?  php echo $row['mpn']; ?>">

</form>

<p id="result"> </p>
```

Comment: Where do you call `sendIt`? Where is the element with id `result`? Please post the full html.

Comment: There is still no element with the id `result`.

Comment: Sorry didn't show correctly.